# Odoo: How to check Module has been installed or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to inherit form view in XML to set invisible some fields but sometime I will not install that module.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to the model of the view you want to modify:

```
@api.depends()
def _compute_module_x_installed(self):
    for record in self:
        module = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([
            ('name', '=', 'the_module_name')
        ])
        if module and module.state == 'installed':
            record.update({
                'module_x_installed': True,
            })

module_x_installed = fields.Boolean(
    compute='_compute_module_x_installed',
    string='Is X installed?',
)
```

That way you'll have a field which will indicate you whether the module is installed or not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @forvas, but I want to modify fields in XML file and your suggestion is in PY file. I don't understand whether how your code works with xml file If I want to modify a module but I never install that module. Sorry for my stupidity. Please help me know what should I do?

Comment: I understand better what you need. The correct way to do that is to create two modules, the main one, with your main functionality, and a secondary one which only adds the XML code to make invisible those fields (the code will be some simple lines like `<attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>`). This secondary module must depend (in the `__manifest__.py`) on your main module and the module which created the fields you're making invisible (the one which will be installed or not).

Comment: The name of the model inside self.env[ ] must be a string, the quotes are missing.

Comment: @RubénCabrera that's true, I forgot them, thak you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the current status of the module with the help of ir_module_module database table.

ir.module.module model Odoo create a new database table which named is ir_module_module where we can search the status of our module through SQL Query using Pgadmin Tools

```
select state from ir_module_module where name='Your_module_name(technical_name)';
```

If we get the result is **' installed '**  in out query it means 
our module is installed in our database.